# select values in a form not getting submitted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, html-select, form-submit

I'm not exactly sure what I'm missing, when I use the dev tools the form shows up properly in the html but the only value that is not being submitted it the one in the drop down.

I looked at my database and it's not submitting any value at all what am I doing wrong, I posted my code below.

******************the form********************

```
= form_for @menu_price do |f|
  - if @menu_price.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      h2 = "#{pluralize(@menu_price.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this menu_price from being saved:"
      ul
        - @menu_price.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
          li = message

  .form-group
    = f.label Category
    = f.select :category_id,  options_for_select( @categories_options),{prompt: "Select a category"}
  .form-group
    = f.label :price
    = f.number_field :price
  .form-group
    = f.label :description
    = f.text_field :description
  .form-group
    = f.label :serves
    = f.text_field :serves

  = f.submit
  = link_to 'Back', menu_prices_path, class:'button'
```

******************Controller******************

```
class MenuPricesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_menu_price, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @menu_prices = MenuPrice.all
  end


  def show
    @categories = Category.all
  end

  def new
    @menu_price = MenuPrice.new
    @categories_options = Category.all.map{|u| [ u.name, u.id ] }
  end

  def edit
    @categories_options = Category.all.map{|u| [ u.name, u.id ] }
  end


  def create
    @menu_price = MenuPrice.new(menu_price_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @menu_price.save
        format.html { redirect_to @menu_price, notice: 'Menu price was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @menu_price }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @menu_price.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @menu_price.update(menu_price_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @menu_price, notice: 'Menu price was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @menu_price }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @menu_price.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @menu_price.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to menu_prices_url, notice: 'Menu price was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

    def set_menu_price
      @menu_price = MenuPrice.find(params[:id])
    end

    def menu_price_params
      params.require(:menu_price).permit(:category, :price, :description, :serves)
    end
end
```

Comment: Do you get any error or checked the console log?
There may be a problem with `mass assignment` or `rollback` issue.
Could you paste your console log here if possible?

Comment: how do I check for errors in the console log? It didn't throw any exceptions when I submitted the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to whitelist `category_id` not `category`.Change your `menu_price_params` to

```
def menu_price_params
   params.require(:menu_price).permit(:category_id, :price, :description, :serves)
end
```

Comment: you get the best answer since you had the solution first

Answer (score 1):

In your view you have

```
  = f.select :category_id
```

while in your MenuPricesController you have

```
params.require(:menu_price).permit(:category, ..)
```

Just change the `:category` to `:category_id`

Comment: Category(#56521180) expected, got String(#19499820) when submit